# How to use angular-cli to create a component out of app directory?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a multi-app angular project. In order to share easily components, models, etc. between apps, I decided to have the following structure:

```
src/
 ├─ components/
 │   ├─ user-wizard/
 │   ├─ users-table/
 │   └─ stepper
 ├─ model/
 ├─ services/
 ├─ validators/
 ├─ app-1/
 │   ├─ app.component.html
 │   ├─ app.component.scss
 │   ├─ app.component.spec.ts
 │   ├─ app.component.ts
 │   ├─ app.module.spec.ts
 │   ├─ app.module.ts
 │   ├─ app-routing.module.ts
 │   └─ pages/
 ├─ app-2/
 │     :
 │     :
 │     :
 ├─ index.html
 ├─ main-1.ts
 ├─ main-2.ts
 │     :
 │     :
```

(I defined all apps in `angular-cli.json` using [appRoot](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/6079) attribute.)

In order to create a new page, for example, I can do:

```
ng g component --app=<app-name> pages/<pageName>
```

However, when I want to create a new component, it will be created inside one of the apps. If no `app` argument is passed, it will be created under first app:

```
ng g component components/<componentName>
```

**My question is:**
Is there any way to tell angular-cli to create a component under a directory **which is not inside any app**?

Comment: This was asked earlier this week, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493935/how-to-ng-generate-module-or-component-inside-specific-folder-other-than-app-fol). The comment tells the story.

Comment: Thanks! what a pity...